# Customizing ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource

Tags: java, spring, jstl

I am using Spring3 along with JSTL. This is regarding Internationalization.
In my JSP I've defined - 

and I am using ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource class of Spring to achieve Internationalization.
I want to customize the ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource so that it will pick up value of key 'error.name.100' if present, else it will pick up value for key 'error.name'.
Similarly if key 'error.address.100' is not present, it will pick value of key 'error.address'
Can this be achievable?